# How to adjust the font in a \newcommand math expression to the environment

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex

I'm writing my thesis about the gas NO2. The correct way to write this is `$NO_2$`. Currently, I have a macro defined to make typing easier:

`\newcommand{\notwo}[0]{\chem{NO_2}\xspace}`

`\chem` is a macro defined in the [Copernicus](http://www.atmospheric-chemistry-and-physics.net/submission/latex_instructions.html) package:

```
\def\testbx{bx}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chem}[1]{\ensuremath{%
\mathcode`-="0200\mathcode`\=="003D% no space around "-" and "="
\ifx\testbx\f@series\mathbf{#1}\else\mathrm{#1}\fi}}
```

However, I'd like to expand this a bit more. Especially, when I'm in sans-serif, I want `\notwo` to be sans-serif, and when I'm in sans-serif-bold, I want `\notwo` to be sans-serif-bold.

I'm using xelatex, and I'm using system-wide installed *Myraid Pro* font (OTF) via the line

```
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,ItalicFont={MyriadPro-It},BoldFont={MyriadPro-Bold}]{Myriad Pro}.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the [`mhchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package for a general approach to chemical formulas.

Comment: thanks - that works like a charm :) `mhchem` needs to be loaded after `amsmath` to avoid some _package option clash_ errors, though.

Comment: @JosephWright if your comment were an answer, I'd accept it because it circumvents my problem in the most elegant way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the [`mhchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package for a general approach to chemical formulas. This allows the simple syntax

```
\ce{NO2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the tests and define a new math alphabet:

```
\makeatletter
\def\test@bx{bx}
\edef\test@sf{\sfdefault}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chem}[1]{\ensuremath{%
  \mathcode`-="0200 \mathcode`\=="003D % no space around "-" and "="
  \ifx\f@family\test@sf
    \ifx\test@bx\f@series
      \let\next\mathsfbf
    \else
      \let\next\mathsf
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx\test@bx\f@series
      \let\next\mathbf
    \else
      \let\next\mathrm
    \fi
  \fi
  \next{#1}}}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - it definitelly points into the right direction.
However, I have a problem that in a bold-sf heading, `\notwo` is only bold, and not sf.
I'm using xelatex, and I'm using system-wide installed Myraid Pro font (OTF) via the line `\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,ItalicFont={MyriadPro-It},BoldFont={MyriadPro-Bold}]{Myriad Pro}`. I suppose that's where my problem lies ...

Comment: @andreas-h See edited message. However, you should add a MWE to show how you get sans serif headings.